# $f$ differentiable, $f(x)$ rational if $x$ rational; $f(x)$ irrational if $x$ irrational. Is $f$ a linear function?

Tags: real-analysis, functions, irrational-numbers, rational-functions

Let $f$ be an everywhere differentiable function whose domain consists of all real numbers. Assume that $f(x)$ is rational for rational $x$ and irrational for irrational $x$. Can we conclude that $f$ is a linear function?

Comment: See [this](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/48910/smooth-functions-for-which-fx-is-rational-if-and-only-if-x-is-rational) and [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/13373/smooth-functions-for-which-fx-is-rational-if-and-only-if-x-is-rational).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No. As mentioned in the posts linked in my comment above, the function
$$
f(x)=\cases{   {1\over x-1}+1,& $x\le 0$ \cr {1\over x+1}-1, &$x\ge 0$ }
$$
has the required properties and is not linear.