# Describe the set of all continuous functions which send rationals to rationals and irrationals to irrationals

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Some linear functions are surely in this set, are they the only examples?

Added: It seems like a very hard task even to describe all linear functions that are in, because, for example, we do not know is $f(x)=\pi x+e$ rational or irrational when $x=1$

Comment: Hint: What are the real operations that make irrationals stay irrational?

Comment: Polynomials with irrational roots are out. I don't know if all transcendental functions are, but log or $e^x$ are for sure, since they map natural numbers to transcendental.

Comment: @Chickenmancer Also polynomials that have $a_0$ irrational do not qualify since $P(0)=a_0$

Comment: Also even exponential functions are out - I tried [if $2^\pi$ was irrational](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=is+2%5Epi+irrational) and Wolfram Alpha didn't know. I suppose this is an open question.

Comment: Excellent observation. Constant irrational/rational too.

Comment: Also, if $f$ sends rationals to irrationals and $g$ irrationals to irrationals then the composition $f \circ g$ will not qualify.

Comment: There are more functions, even smooth functions: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/13373/smooth-functions-for-which-fx-is-rational-if-and-only-if-x-is-rational. But not polynomials: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2202087/fx-axb-for-some-a-b-in-mathbbq-if-f-mathbbq-subset-mathbbq-and and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/262410/find-all-polynomials-that-fix-mathbb-q-and-the-irrationals

Comment: My oh my, $f$ sending rationals to irrationals cannot be continuous, my bad.

Comment: Actually, I think all linear functions $y = mx+c$, where $m,c$ are rational satisfy your example. Since the set is closed for rational numbers addition, subtraction, multiplication and division, then this won't produce any irrational numbers. Using the opposite argument, then any irrational numbers cannot become rational.

Comment: @TobyMak Yes, all those are in, but, for example linear $f(x)=\pi \cdot x$ is obviously not.

Comment: $f(x)=\pi \cdot x - \frac {1}{\pi}$ is also not.

Comment: Yes, from your examples not all linear function satisfy your condition, but the only polynomials that do are linear functions.

Comment: I do not know will there be some everywhere continuous but nowhere differentiable ones that will belong to the set.

Comment: In additional to linear polynomials with rational coefficients, you could build piecewise linear functions that do this.

Comment: @TheoBendit Is every piece also linear with rational coefficients?